# UIScrollview zoom and enable paging simultaneously

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

Can i implement both the paging and zooming of imageview  in a uiscrollview at the same time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. You can do it.
In each page of the *mainScrollView* add a *subScrollView* containing the *imageView*. You need to do the following things.

1. Set *maximumZoomScale* for *subScrollView*

   ```
   [subScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0f];   // You can set any value
   ```

   This value is calculated based on the size of the image displayed in the imageView.
2. In the *viewForZoomingInScrollView:* method of the *subScrollView* return the *imageView*

   ```
   - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

       return imageView;
   }
   ```
3. Enable paging in *mainScrollView*

   ```
   mainScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
   ```

   You have to write further code to handle paging in the *mainScrollView*.

Comment: can you explain it. If i am adding a scrollview on mainscrollview how can i implement paging on main scrollview. All the touches will go on to the subscrollview, right.

Comment: @user760321, If you scroll the *subScrollView* and if it reaches its end, the touch will be transferred to the *mainScrollView*. So the *mainScrollView* will move to next page if available.

Comment: @user760321, I have implemented this in one of my project. Wish you luck on implementing this :-)

Comment: How can i know While moving to the next page. None of the delegates are invoking in this condition.

Comment: @user760321, Hi. Can you explain your problem?

Comment: I want to know when the user is moving to the next page, that is swiping and going to next page. How can i know this. None of the uiscrollview delegates of uimainview are invoking in this condition.

Comment: @user760321, mainScrollView's delegate should invoke the paging.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! BTW, if you have just an image view in your scrollView, you can use [[scrollview subviews] objectAtIndex:0] to get the imageView.

Comment: I think **[[scrollview subviews] objectAtIndex:0]** won't return the *imageView*, because scroll view already contains some subviews like the horizontal and vertical scroll indicators, which in turn are UIImageViews. So, you better set **tag** for your image view like, ***imageView.tag = 100;** and, you can access it as **[scrollView viewWithTag:100];**

Comment: @EmptyStack, could you explain more detailed about this method? Now I add a second UIScrollView along with main UIScrollView. In the second one, I add a TapDetectImageView as subview to receive double tap gesture. but in running, it cannot get any gesture at all. Really appreciate if you could share few of code on this.

Comment: @LetBulletFlies, I think you have added the tap gesture recognizer to image view. Add the tap gesture recognizer to **subScrollView**, not to image view. And sorry man, I can't not share the code now.